# how can we define static variable and call in html file in node.js?

Tags: node.js

I want to define variable in app.js file then after use this variable in  whole/any html page.

Fore example:

```
app.js
var title = 'mytask';

index.html
<%=title%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do the same using ejs

But if you want to use the varibale on hmtl page, you need to pass the title while rendering the page .

Say there is an "index.html"

```
res.render("index", {title :title});
```

now you can easily use the title variable in index.html

```
<div>{{title}}</div>
```

Comment: thanks for you suggestion but I want to use this variable without pass in render file.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called a **local variable**. If you're using Express (which I assume you do), then you have two kinds of locals, which are both sent to the views automatically, without passing them manually in each of your routes:

- **app locals**: these are alive persistently for the entire lifetime of the application, you can use them anywhere where the `app` object is in scope. ([more info](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.locals))
- **response locals**: these are tied to the lifecycle and scope of a single request/response object ([more info](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.locals))